# Running ubuntu from USB hard drive in Macosx?

Tags: 14.04, usb-drive, macbook

I have a macbook pro, just bought western digital externall 500gb hard drive connects through usb. i want to run ubuntu linux from my usb hard drive, as i have no disk space in my Macbook. Is this possible?

I created 2 partitions, BOOT and ROOT in my western digital drive. I tried installing ubuntu, debian, fedora etc.. and several versions and it freezes/crashes during install. It freezes "Detecting filesystems..." during install.

It loooks easy but very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install a Live USB with persistent storage on the HDD (the same way you create a linux USB pen) tough i dont know the programs you can use in mac for that purpose  =( but nothing a little research wont help =)

Comment: Nope. Its not working! Seems the only way to install ubuntu is HDD. its gets stuck installing to USB drive. Anybody tried it?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BeVcHpzVjFw you tried this?